# How to display SQL search results in a datagrid using WPF

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datagrid

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();

        sc.Open();
        com.Connection = sc;
        string sql;
        {
             sql = "SELECT FROM WolfAcademyForm WHERE [Forename] == 'txtSearch.Text';";
            {
                grdSearch.ItemsSource = sql;
                sc.Close();
            }
```

This is the code that I have, When I press the search button nothing shows up... Can someone please help me with this problem, I don't get any errors

Comment: You assinged `ItemsSource` property your sql string? That's wrong.. You can use a datareader and fill a datatable then bind to your grid..

Comment: Binding is not right. Also sql seems not right referring to `SELECT FROM` and `==` in query

Comment: You should execute command and result assign to ItemSource

Comment: @HassanNisar I put a break point in, and it says sql null, would you have any ideas on how to make it search?

Comment: @BenNixon. Declaration of `string sql;` and then putting brackets under it doesn't make any sense. Also your query is not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problems**:

SQL query is not right:

1. It should be like `SELECT * FROM TABLENAME`.
2. In WHERE clause `[Forename] == 'txtSearch.Text'`, `==` should `=` and Textbox value should be concatenated using `+`.

Fixed Code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

     string sConn = @"Data Source=MYDS;Initial Catalog=MyCat;
                 User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPass;";


    using(SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(sConn))
    {
        sc.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM WolfAcademyForm WHERE [Forename]= @Forename";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, sc);       
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Forename", txtSearch.Text);

        using(SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(com))
        {
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           adapter.Fill(dt);
           grdSearch.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;              
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))

    {

        CmdString = "SELECT FROM WolfAcademyForm WHERE [Forename] == " + txtSearch.Text + ";"
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Employee");

        sda.Fill(dt);

        grdSearch.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

    }
```