# Show the result of a SQL query in a DataGrid in WPF App

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, xaml, datagrid

The result of a query is in a SqlDataReader and it can have flexible number of columns and numerous number of rows.

```
string mySQLQuery= "select * from myTable";
SqlCommand myTableCommand = new SqlCommand(mySQLQuery, MyConnection);
SqlDataReader myReader = null;
myReader = myTableCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

What I wish to do is to show the result in a DataGrid. The .xaml part is like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="myDataGrid" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="Cell" AutoGenerateColumns="True" AlternatingRowBackground="LightCyan" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="True" Background="WhiteSmoke" Margin="13,27,8,110" CanUserSortColumns="True">
</DataGrid>
```

The following block of code in .xaml.cs part for showing the values of my table into DataGrid is completely hypothetical and just to clarify what I want to do:

```
// suppose that I have read the list of headers (column names)
// and suppose a button is clicked and an event is triggered and these codes are fit into that event
List<string> myHeaders = new List<string>() { "ID" , "Name" , "Country" , "City" };
myDataGrid.headers= myHeaders; // no method called "header" in reality
While (myReader.Read())
{
 myDataGrid.RowValues = myReader // no method called "RowValues" in reality
}
```

I prefer the solution without an individual class for managing each column of the DataGrid, because then it's hard to have flexible number of columns.
And obviously I wish my results to be like this:

```
 ID   |  Name  |  Country  | City
------------------------------------
 123  |  John  |  England  | London
------------------------------------
 456  |  Jane  |  Ireland  | Dublin
 ...     ...        ...       ...
```

Non of the answers in this link helped:
[How to display SQL search results in a datagrid using WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649840/how-to-display-sql-search-results-in-a-datagrid-using-wpf)

Comment: Try using `DataTable` to add rows and columns and later assigned the datatable as grid's `ItemsSource` property. You don't need `ItemsSource="{Binding}` in that case in XAML.

Comment: @user1672994 Thank you. Seems like a good solution but I get some weird result; a table with this columns: "`RowError, RowState, Table, ItemArray, HasErrors`".
For assigning the DataTable to my  myDataGrid.ItemsSource  I had to first make the cast of DataTable to IEnumerable. So I did this:
`myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myDataTable.AsEnumerable();`
No error, but as I said, strange result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:

Thanks to “user1672994”, this solution now works:

```
string mySQLQuery= "select * from myTable";
SqlCommand myTableCommand = new SqlCommand(mySQLQuery, MyConnection);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(myTableCommand );
a.Fill(dt);
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```